# Azure RHEL Linux VM updates , Gen2 supported?

Tags: azure, azure-linux

I am trying to add a RHEL8.2Gen2 VM to automated patching but its failing . I get the hybrid runbook worker is not running error when I run the trouble shooter.

I also get the following error when I go to the "Check For Updates" option on the VM page .

> Update operation on 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', machine:
> 'hexdev-linux02-RHEL8.2'. Error details:
> {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The selected VM image is not
> supported for VM Guest patch operations. Learn more at:
> [https://aka.ms/VMGuestPatchingCompatibility"}}](https://aka.ms/VMGuestPatchingCompatibility%22%7D%7D)

Looking at the webpage the error advises me to look at it says RHEL8.2 is supported, but it does not mention anything about Gen1 or Gen2 VMs.

Everything works when I use a Gen1 type VM image for the same RHEL8.2 distro.

Can anyone confirm if  Check for Updates and automated patching for RHEL8.2 image should work if you use a Gen2 VM?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [RHEL 8 image types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/redhat/redhat-images#rhel-8-image-types) Gen 2 type VM image will not work

- Generation 2 doesn't support the operating system you want to run on the virtual machine.
- Generation 2 doesn't support the boot method you want to use and Gen 2 are not available in every region it's depends upon the availability of the VM size. see [Hyper-V feature compatibility by generation and guest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/hyper-v-feature-compatibility-by-generation-and-guest).

**Features included in generation 2**

- Increased memory, Intel Software Guard Extensions (Intel SGX), and virtualized persistent memory
- Uses new UEFI-based boot architecture rather than the BIOS-based architecture used by generation 1

***Note: Once you created virtual machine's generation you won't be able to change generation so, please considerations before you choose a generation. I would advise you to use Gen1 as it is right now.***

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Support for generation 2 VMs on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/generation-2#features-and-capabilities)

[Should I create a generation 1 or 2 virtual machine in Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v)

[Automatic VM guest patching for Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/automatic-vm-guest-patching)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got more info than I needed.  So does the list in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/automatic-vm-guest-patching indicate a Gen2 VM running RHEL8.x  is not supported  because the SKU 8-gen2 is not listed ?

Comment: Sorry the answer is not clear. To me it looks like a RHEL8 Gen2 VM is   supported on Azure , but the automated patching feature I require  is not because its a Gen2 SKU. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: Added an image to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just need to confirm that the "plan" in portal dashboard shows the same detail as SKU. I need to find away to query the VM to see 100% what SKU it us running.

Comment: Please stop using comments for conversation. Also, this question belongs on ServerFault, not Stack Overflow.